# Windows Server 2012 Standard - Can ping google.com, but cannot access on Firefox

Tags: windows, networking

I have a Win Server 2012 Standard that I'm replacing a Win Server 2003 R2 Standard.

After migrating Active Directory and DNS over to the 2012 server and making it the Global Catalog DC.

1. I can ping and tracert google.com, using local ip and 8.8.8.8 as DNS for the local network settings on the server.
2. I can also RDP into the Win 2012 server.
3. All other workstations, including the old Win 2003 server can access google.com in browser.
4. dcdiag on win server 2012 has no failures.
5. Firewall is off for all networks. No proxy scripts for either IE or FF.

The only thing that I'm having an issue with is hitting websites on a browser. The server will be running quickbooks so we need connectivity.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you disabled IE Enhanced Security?  https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-ie-esc-in-windows-server-2012/  Have you tried other browsers, such as Chrome or Firefox?  You would have to download the installers for those from another system...

Answer (score 0):

It was the router after all. After restoring factory defaults, the router failed to power on. Changed router and everything works now.